# How to write a resolver for a GraphQL subscription using graphql-java and graphql-java-servlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I try to setup a Spring Boot based GraphQL service (based on project `graphql-spring-boot-starter`, https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot), which does **not** use `graphql-java-tools`, but builds the RuntimeWiring manually/programmatically. GraphQL queries and mutations work just fine that way. However, I have problems to make subscriptions work.

I've added the following wiring to bind the DataFetcher for the subscription:

```
RuntimeWiring.Builder runtimeWiringBuilder =
    newRuntimeWiring()
    ...
        .type(TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring("Subscription")
            .dataFetcher("stockQuotes", gqlService::stockQuotes)
        );
```

And my resolver function returns correctly an `org.reactivestream.Publisher`

```
Publisher<StockPriceUpdate> stockQuotes(DataFetchingEnvironment env) {
    return stockTickerPublisher.getPublisher();
}
```

However, if I call my subscription from GraphiQL or GraphQL Playground, I get the following error:
"No serializer found for class graphql.execution.reactive.CompletionStageMappingPublisher" (stack trace below).

It looks like that `GraphQLObjectMapper` from lib `graphql-java-servlet` tries to serialize the result, which is a (wrapped) `org.reactivestream.Publisher`, directly as a JSON result. That does not make sense, of course. Instead it should subscribe as listener to the publisher and push updates via the WebSocket whenever the Publisher emits the next update.

As far as I understood, `graphql-java-servlet` already has built-in support for subscriptions via WebSockets. Unfortunately there is no plain-vanilla example available, which does subscriptions *without using graphql-tools*.

Any ideas how I can get this working? Thanks a lot!

The relevant parts of my `application.yml` file are those:

```
server:
  port: 9200

graphql:
  servlet:
    mapping: /graphql
    enabled: true
    corsEnabled: true
    websocket:
      enabled: true
      path: /graphql
    subscriptions:
      websocket:
        path: /graphql
```

The schema (excerpt):

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
  subscription : Subscription
}

type Subscription {
  stockQuotes: StockPriceUpdate!
}

type StockPriceUpdate {
  dateTime : String
  stockCode : String
  stockPrice : Float
  stockPriceChange : Float
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class graphql.execution.reactive.CompletionStageMappingPublisher and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["data"])
    at graphql.servlet.GraphQLObjectMapper.serializeResultAsJson(GraphQLObjectMapper.java:95) ~[graphql-java-servlet-7.1.1.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.query(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:339) ~[graphql-java-servlet-7.1.1.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.lambda$init$4(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:209) ~[graphql-java-servlet-7.1.1.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doRequest(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:306) ~[graphql-java-servlet-7.1.1.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doRequestAsync(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:297) ~[graphql-java-servlet-7.1.1.jar:na]
    at graphql.servlet.AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.doPost(AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet.java:327) ~[graphql-java-servlet-7.1.1.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class graphql.execution.reactive.CompletionStageMappingPublisher and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["data"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:313) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:718) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3219) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at graphql.servlet.GraphQLObjectMapper.serializeResultAsJson(GraphQLObjectMapper.java:93) ~[graphql-java-servlet-7.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried this `and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)`?

Comment: I cannot configure the ObjectMapper, since it is used by graphql-servlet library internaly. But as written above: It anyway does not make any sense that the Publisher gets serialized to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above stack trace comes when you try to use electron based `GraphiQL.app` which was not updated since Mar 22, 2018 (v.0.7.2). So, to fix an issue and see subscription working:

1. Don't use `GraphiQL.app`;
2. Add following dependency to your `pom.xml` to expose resent `/graphiql` endpoint from your spring boot micro service (for testing):

```
        <!-- Graph(i)QL tool: for development -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

3. `graphiql` by default expects that subscriptions are exposed over `/subscriptions` endpoint. So:

   - either change `graphql.subscriptions.websocket.path` from `/graphql` to `/subscriptions`;
   - or customize `graphiql` in your `application.yml` (to reflect `graphql` configuration):

```
graphiql:
  endpoint:
    subscriptions: /graphql
```

After restart you can go to `http://localhost:9200/graphiql` and run subscription, as:

```
subscription StockCodeSubscription {
    stockQuotes {
        dateTime
        stockCode
        stockPrice
        stockPriceChange
    }
}
```

Should work!

Comment: Thanks! That was the missing piece of information. I actually used GraphiQL.app. And also tried the Web-based GraphiQL, but was not aware that it listens to another subscription endpoint.

Comment: @vaa Could you please tell me how can I make subscriptions working when i have a context path for my spring boot app? By default my subscription url is `http://localhost:8080/subscriptions` . I tried setting the property `graphql.servlet.subscriptions.websocket.path=/<<context>>/subscriptions` but it still calls `http://localhost:8080/subscriptions`

Comment: According to the classes `GraphQLWebsocketAutoConfiguration` and `GraphQLWsServerEndpointRegistration` from `graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure` the `websocketPath`, which takes value from `graphql.servlet.subscriptions.websocket.path`, have to be qualified from root `/`. So, you have to specify your `<<context>>` in configuration.  Sorry for the later reply.